# Lookahead behaviour inside repeated alternation group

Tags: regex, pcre

A regex like `(?:(?=abc)|[abc])+` will match a string consisting of `a`, `b` and `c` until the lookahead-condition is met.
E.g. for the string `acbababcaaa` it will match `acbab` - stoping right in front of the first `abc`, though it could advance to the end of the string if it were excessively greedy.

We can force this by adding `$` to the end of the pattern (`(?:(?=abc)|[abc])+$`) - now it actually match to the end of the string.

When we now change the repetition to being possesive (`(?:(?=abc)|[abc])++$`) - it will match `bcaaa` - thus the first position, where the lookahead can't match anymore.

Could anyone explain the reasons for these behaviours?

Comment: The first will only match the start of string if do not use a global search mode (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/t9zDtJ/1)), not `abcab`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are obviously correct - I had the wrong string in copy+paste. Updated the question.

Comment: The point here I believe is that in PCRE the index is not moving when you  have a *zero-width match*. Just note that the behavior in JS is different since JS regex forces the regex  index advance after a zero-width match. In some situations, this behavior is great (when you are matching consecutive zero-width and non-zero-width substrings, and - as in this case - there can be "glitches". In the last example, the possessive quantifier requires the end of string right after the branch matches, so all zero-width matches fail the match, and you only get the last chunk containing no `abc`

Comment: When you force engine to advance possessively it doesn't backtrack anymore to first group `(?:...)`. After seeing `abc` with that positive lookahead engine exists from whole group and expects end of input string `$`. It's not there and can't backtrack to try other side of alternation so it fails completely. It then starts from next character of previous start position. It's equal to `(?>(?=abc)|[abc])+$`. This process continues and it fails whenever it sees an `abc` in input string that is not followed by end of of string `$`.

Comment: [My last comment above should read *the possessive quantifier requires the end of string right after the branch matches with no backtracking allowed* - comment appeared too long]

Comment: Please what *index* are you referring to and how does a *zero-width assertion* change it? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @revo: I did not say that. I only mentioned that PCRE has a specific way of [*Advancing After a Zero-Length Regex Match*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html#advance).

Comment: I mean this part *JS regex forces the regex index advance after a zero-width match.* @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @revo: That is not actually strictly related  to this question. Just switch the PCRE and JS options for [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/2h9Pn9/1) - you will see what I meant.

Comment: Ok that's something else however *(with both phrases now clarified in this context)* you talked nearly 4 lines about *zero-length match* while there is no *zero-length match* related thing in question at all but a *zero-length assertion*. So what's the point? @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you force engine to advance possessively it doesn't backtrack anymore to first group `(?:...)`.

After seeing `abc` with that positive lookahead engine exists from whole group and expects end of input string `$`. It's not there and can't backtrack to try the other side of alternation either so it fails completely and all previous consumed characters by `[abc]` is freed and pointer is reset to the next character of previous start position of whole pattern.

You could write it with an atomic group `(?>(?=abc)|[abc])+$` to more explicitly express the difference. This process continues and it fails whenever it sees an `abc` in input string that is not followed by end of of string `$`.

That's why `bcaaa` characters are matched at the end because positive lookahead never is going to happen after `a` before `bcaaa` is consumed.